# Executing .sql file with variable from PHP script

Tags: php, mysql

I have very long SQL file which includes `$variable` in format like:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `$variable` $$
    CREATE TRIGGER `TEMP` BEFORE INSERT ON `5_2012`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      set NEW.chour = timediff(NEW.exit, NEW.enter);
      set NEW.total = timediff(NEW.exit, NEW.enter);
...
```

I need a way to execute this script each time with different table names (`$variable`).

I am using MySQL.

Comment: What database server are you using?  Is that MySQL syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Change your .sql file into a .php script
Add a header to the top, and add the mime type. If i can remember correctly, it's application/x-sql. 
Echo out each variable.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/x-sql");
?>

DELIMITER $$ 
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `<?= $variable; ?>` $$
CREATE TRIGGER `TEMP` BEFORE INSERT ON `5_2012` 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN   
    set NEW.chour = timediff(NEW.exit, NEW.enter);
    set NEW.total = timediff(NEW.exit, NEW.enter);
```